# Реализация переключения по клику

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, не могу полностью реализовать переключение по клику. Нужно просто в одном диве убирать класс в другой добавлять и т.д. но первый див переключаются а вот дальше не идёт, подскажите где я тут накосячил или напишите правильное решение. Сильно не пинайте, я только начинаю :)

```js
var i = 0;
var quizPanel = document.getElementsByClassName('quiz-panel');
document.getElementById('next').onclick = function() {

  document.getElementsByClassName("quiz-panel")[i].classList.remove("in-active");
  if(i == quizPanel.length) {
    i = 0;
  } else {
    i++;
  }
  document.getElementsByClassName("quiz-panel")[i].classList.add("in-active");
}
document.getElementById('prev').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("quiz-panel")[i].classList.remove("in-active");
  if(i == 0) {
    i = 3;
  } else {
    i--
  }
  document.getElementsByClassName("quiz-panel")[i].classList.add("in-active");
}
```

```css
.quiz-selection,
.quiz-selection-panel {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.quiz-panel {
  display: none;
}

.in-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="quiz-panel in-active">
  <div class="quiz-content">
    <h2>На какой праздник или кому выбираете шарики?</h2>
    <ul class="quiz-selection">
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="holidays" id="happy-birthday" checked>
        <label for="happy-birthday">День Рождение</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="holidays" id="family-celebration">
        <label for="family-celebration">Семейный праздник</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="holidays" id="new-year">
        <label for="new-year">Новый год</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="holidays" id="corporative">
        <label for="corporative">Корпоратив</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="holidays" id="outlet">
        <label for="outlet">Выпускной</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="holidays" id="another">
        <label for="another">Другой</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="holidays" id="for-myself">
        <label for="for-myself">Простотак, порадовать себя и близких</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="quiz-content-panel">
    <ul class="quiz-selection-panel">
      <li class="quiz-selection-item active">
        <span>1</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item">
        <span>2</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item">
        <span>3</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item">
        <span>4</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item">
        <span>5</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="next" type="button">Следующий вопрос</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="quiz-panel">
  <div class="quiz-content">
    <h2>Какие шарики вам нравятся больше всего?</h2>
    <ul class="quiz-selection">
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="like-ball" id="foil" checked>
        <label for="foil">Фольгированные</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="like-ball" id="conventional-gel">
        <label for="conventional-gel">Обычные гелевые</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="like-ball" id="conventional-air">
        <label for="conventional-air">Обычные воздушные</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="like-ball" id="with-a-pattern">
        <label for="with-a-pattern">С узором</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="like-ball" id="hero">
        <label for="hero">В виде игрушки или персонажа</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="like-ball" id="number">
        <label for="number">В виде цифр</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="like-ball" id="another-ball">
        <label for="another-ball">Другой</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="like-ball" id="personal-ball">
        <label for="personal-ball">Есть фото того, что понравился</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="quiz-content-panel">
    <ul class="quiz-selection-panel">
      <li class="quiz-selection-item active">
        <span>1</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item active">
        <span>2</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item">
        <span>3</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item">
        <span>4</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item">
        <span>5</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="prev" type="button">Предыдущий вопрос</button>
    <button id="next" type="button">Следующий вопрос</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="quiz-panel">
  <div class="quiz-content">
    <h2>Подскажите ваш примерный бюджет?</h2>
    <ul class="quiz-selection">
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="budget" id="little-many" checked>
        <label for="little-many">10-30 бел.руб</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="budget" id="average-price">
        <label for="average-price">30-55 бел.руб</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="budget" id="great-price">
        <label for="great-price">55-100 бел.руб</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="budget" id="maximum-price">
        <label for="maximum-price">Более 100 бел.руб</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="budget" id="huge-budget">
        <label for="huge-budget">Бюджет не главное, важно чтобы понравилось</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="quiz-content-panel">
    <ul class="quiz-selection-panel">
      <li class="quiz-selection-item active">
        <span>1</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item active">
        <span>2</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item active">
        <span>3</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item">
        <span>4</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item">
        <span>5</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="prev" type="button">Предыдущий вопрос</button>
    <button id="next" type="button">Следующий вопрос</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Цитата:использование одного и того же идентификатора для нескольких элементов не остановит загрузку страницы, но при попытке выбрать элемент по идентификатору единственным возвращаемым элементом является первый элемент с указанным идентификатором. Не говоря уже о том, что использование одного и того же идентификатора даже не является допустимым HTML.

Вы по ````document.getElementById('next')```` ловите только первый элемент, либо перейдите на класс, и ловите по номеру (i счетчик у вас есть). но я бы вынес кнопки следующий , предыдущий в свой див, и скрывал бы предыдущий у первого вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас получается несколько эл-тов на странице с тем же id. Если быть точным, то эти:

```
<button id="prev" type="button">Предыдущий вопрос</button> 
<button id="next" type="button">Следующий вопрос</button>
```

Вам надо вынести эти кнопки вне вопросов (в самый конец, например), и в зависимости от шага - скрывать/показывать нужные
К примеру, простую функцию можно написать для этого:

```
var prev = document.getElementById('prev');
var next = document.getElementById('next');
var count = quizPanel.length-1;
function showButtons(prev,next,step,count){
    if (step < 1){
        prev.style.display='none';
        next.style.display='block';
    } else if (step == count) {
        next.style.display='none';
        prev.style.display='block';
    } else {
        prev.style.display='block';
        next.style.display='block';
    }
}
showButtons(prev,next,i,count);
```

`step` в аргумментах это `i`

```js
var i = 0;
var quizPanel = document.getElementsByClassName('quiz-panel');
var prev = document.getElementById('prev');
var next = document.getElementById('next');
var count = quizPanel.length-1;
showButtons(prev,next,i,count);
document.getElementById('next').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("quiz-panel")[i].classList.remove("in-active");
  if(i == quizPanel.length) {
    i = 0;
  } else {
    i++;
  }
  document.getElementsByClassName("quiz-panel")[i].classList.add("in-active");
  showButtons(prev,next,i,count);
}
document.getElementById('prev').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("quiz-panel")[i].classList.remove("in-active");
  if(i == 0) {
    i = 3;
  } else {
    i--
  }
  document.getElementsByClassName("quiz-panel")[i].classList.add("in-active");
  showButtons(prev,next,i,count);
}

function showButtons(prev,next,step,count){
    if (step < 1){
   prev.style.display='none';
     next.style.display='block';
    } else if (step == count) {
   next.style.display='none';
     prev.style.display='block';
    } else {
   prev.style.display='block';
     next.style.display='block';
    } 
}
```

```css
.quiz-selection,
.quiz-selection-panel {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.quiz-panel {
    display: none;
}

.in-active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="quiz-panel in-active">
  <div class="quiz-content">
    <h2>На какой праздник или кому выбираете шарики?</h2>
    <ul class="quiz-selection">
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="holidays" id="happy-birthday" checked>
        <label for="happy-birthday">День Рождение</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="holidays" id="family-celebration">
        <label for="family-celebration">Семейный праздник</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="holidays" id="new-year">
        <label for="new-year">Новый год</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="holidays" id="corporative">
        <label for="corporative">Корпоратив</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="holidays" id="outlet">
        <label for="outlet">Выпускной</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="holidays" id="another">
        <label for="another">Другой</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="holidays" id="for-myself">
        <label for="for-myself">Простотак, порадовать себя и близких</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="quiz-content-panel">
    <ul class="quiz-selection-panel">
      <li class="quiz-selection-item active">
        <span>1</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item">
        <span>2</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item">
        <span>3</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item">
        <span>4</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item">
        <span>5</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="quiz-panel">
  <div class="quiz-content">
    <h2>Какие шарики вам нравятся больше всего?</h2>
    <ul class="quiz-selection">
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="like-ball" id="foil" checked>
        <label for="foil">Фольгированные</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="like-ball" id="conventional-gel">
        <label for="conventional-gel">Обычные гелевые</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="like-ball" id="conventional-air">
        <label for="conventional-air">Обычные воздушные</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="like-ball" id="with-a-pattern">
        <label for="with-a-pattern">С узором</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="like-ball" id="hero">
        <label for="hero">В виде игрушки или персонажа</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="like-ball" id="number">
        <label for="number">В виде цифр</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="like-ball" id="another-ball">
        <label for="another-ball">Другой</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="like-ball" id="personal-ball">
        <label for="personal-ball">Есть фото того, что понравился</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="quiz-content-panel">
    <ul class="quiz-selection-panel">
      <li class="quiz-selection-item active">
        <span>1</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item active">
        <span>2</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item">
        <span>3</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item">
        <span>4</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item">
        <span>5</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="quiz-panel">
  <div class="quiz-content">
    <h2>Подскажите ваш примерный бюджет?</h2>
    <ul class="quiz-selection">
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="budget" id="little-many" checked>
        <label for="little-many">10-30 бел.руб</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="budget" id="average-price">
        <label for="average-price">30-55 бел.руб</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="budget" id="great-price">
        <label for="great-price">55-100 бел.руб</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="budget" id="maximum-price">
        <label for="maximum-price">Более 100 бел.руб</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="budget" id="huge-budget">
        <label for="huge-budget">Бюджет не главное, важно чтобы понравилось</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="quiz-content-panel">
    <ul class="quiz-selection-panel">
      <li class="quiz-selection-item active">
        <span>1</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item active">
        <span>2</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item active">
        <span>3</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item">
        <span>4</span>
      </li>
      <li class="quiz-selection-item">
        <span>5</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</div>
<button id="prev" type="button">Предыдущий вопрос</button>
<button id="next" type="button">Следующий вопрос</button>
```